# what can I do to make long to wide format in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this long data. I like to sort this by 30 each and save separately.
Data print like this,
    `A292340
A291630
A278240
A267770
A267490
A261250
A261110
A253150
A252400
A253250
A243890
A243880
A236350
A233740
A233160
A225800
A225060
A225050
A225040
A225130
A219900
A204450
A204480
A204420
A196030
A196220
A167860
A152500
A123320
A122630
.`
This is fairly simple question, but I need your help..
Thank you.
(And how can I make a list out of one results printed? list addtion?

Comment: Do you need for each 30 rows separate column?

Comment: Yes that’s what i need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe need create `MultiIndex` by modulo and floor divide `np.arange` by length of DataFrame and then [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

But if length modulo is not equal `0`  (e.g. `(30 % 12)`), last values are not matched to last column and `None`s are added:

```
N = 12
r = np.arange(len(df))
df.index = [r % N, r // N]
df = df['col'].unstack()
print (df)
          0        1        2
0   A292340  A236350  A196030
1   A291630  A233740  A196220
2   A278240  A233160  A167860
3   A267770  A225800  A152500
4   A267490  A225060  A123320
5   A261250  A225050  A122630
6   A261110  A225040     None
7   A253150  A225130     None
8   A252400  A219900     None
9   A253250  A204450     None
10  A243890  A204480     None
11  A243880  A204420     None
```

**Setup**:

```
d = {'col': ['A292340', 'A291630', 'A278240', 'A267770', 'A267490', 'A261250', 'A261110', 'A253150', 'A252400', 'A253250', 'A243890', 'A243880', 'A236350', 'A233740', 'A233160', 'A225800', 'A225060', 'A225050', 'A225040', 'A225130', 'A219900', 'A204450', 'A204480', 'A204420', 'A196030', 'A196220', 'A167860', 'A152500', 'A123320', 'A122630']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

print (df.head())
       col
0  A292340
1  A291630
2  A278240
3  A267770
4  A267490
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have Pandas and Numpy modules you can use this:

Setup:

```
long_list = ['A292340', 'A291630', 'A278240', 'A267770', 'A267490', 'A261250', 'A261110', 'A253150', 'A252400',
             'A253250', 'A243890', 'A243880', 'A236350', 'A233740', 'A233160', 'A225800', 'A225060', 'A225050',
             'A225040', 'A225130', 'A219900', 'A204450', 'A204480', 'A204420', 'A196030', 'A196220', 'A167860',
             'A152500', 'A123320', 'A122630', 'A292340', 'A291630', 'A278240', 'A267770', 'A267490', 'A261250',
             'A261110', 'A253150', 'A252400', 'A253250', 'A243890', 'A243880', 'A236350', 'A233740', 'A233160',
             'A225800', 'A225060', 'A225050', 'A225040', 'A225130', 'A219900', 'A204450', 'A204480', 'A204420',
             'A196030', 'A196220', 'A167860', 'A152500', 'A123320', 'A122630']
```

Code:

```
number_elements_in_sublist = 30

sublists = []
sublists.append([])
sublist_index = 0
for index, element in enumerate(long_list):
    sublists[sublist_index].append(element)
    if index > 0:
        if (index+1) % number_elements_in_sublist == 0:
            if index == len(long_list)-1:
                break
            sublists.append([])
            sublist_index += 1

for index, sublist in enumerate(sublists):
    print("Sublist Nr." + str(index+1))
    for element in sublist:
        print(element)
```